# Does anyone know the language used to code Orkut?

Tags: asp.net

For sure this question will not help anyone in a heavy way, but it can be useful somehow. In the beginning, all **Orkut** pages had the extension `*.aspx`, but now all pages are **masqueraded** under a `Main#page.aspx`.

Sorry if this `Main#` is an ASP feature, but it does not look like one to me. Does anyone know the language Orkut was coded in? (I meant the language behind the "Main#")

Comment: question is not relevant any more. Because orkut is decommission by google

Answer (score 0):

browsing around, it seems like a lot of the stuff ends up as [.py](http://help.orkut.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=30993&src=top5) (python) files.   From what I remember, Orkut was created, and then bought out by Google, so they may be in the process of switching it over to python, which is a more standard Google Language.

Comment: Does anyone know why Google is pushing python over .. lets say something like Ruby?

Answer (score -1):

Originally written in ASP.NET, then moved to Java (keep .aspx extension for SEO compatibility, and probably the less deep back-end layer was still in ASP.NET and not Java). Main#page.aspx doesn't have anything with the backend language, but with javascript, this was just a front-end feature (implementend using JS) that can be implemented by any one independly of back-end language.

Less deep back-end layer, if wasn't clear, means the back-end features layer closest to de presentation/UI/front-end layer. The one who communicates with a services & data layer (this maybe in Java after 2007)